Дублирование элемента в списке
Может кто-нибудь "на пальцах" объяснить, какое назначение отведено for _ in в следующем коде:
n = [1, 2, 3] 
new_lst = [i for i in n for _ in range(2)] 
print(new_lst)

По условию задачи нужно создать копию каждого элемента в списке, получив следующий результат:
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

Очевидно, что i for i создает копию элемента списка, но чему в дальнейшем присваивается эта самая копия ? Отступу от основного i?

Такая запись:
lst = [1, 2, 3]
new_lst = [i*2 for i in lst]
print(new_lst)  # [2, 4, 6]

называется "list comprehension". Позволяет короткой записью сделать список из другого итерируемого объекта (в данном случае списка).
Она равноценна записи:
new_lst = []
for i in lst:
    new_lst.append(i*2)
print(new_lst)  # [2, 4, 6]

Как и с обычными циклами, можно вызывать цикл в цикле. Например:
lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
new_lst = []
for i in lst:
    for y in i:
        new_lst.append(y*2)
print(new_lst)  # [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

Тоже самое можно записать:
new_lst = [y for i in lst for y in i]
print(new_lst)  # [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

По поводу нижнего подчёркивания а записи for _ in:
Нижним подчёркиванием принято называть переменные, которыми мы не будем пользоваться, но по каким-то причинам мы вынуждены куда-то записать значение.
В итоге получается что запись:
n = [1, 2, 3] 
new_lst = [i for i in n for _ in range(2)] 

то же самое, что и следующий код:
new_lst = []
for i in n:
    for _ in range(2):
        new_lst.append(i)


Огромное смпасбо !

Кажется, в последнем фрагменте порядок циклов перепутал?

@Qwertiy Нет, тут многие путаются, но вложенные list comprehension работают так. Кажется, что тот что справа должен быть внешним, а тот что слева - внутренним. Но по факту наоборот.

@MaxRokitsky, да, проверил.

Конструкция
[i for i in n for _ in range(2)] 

Это то же самое, что и
new_lst = []
for i in n:
    for _ in range(2):
        new_lst.append(i)

Это называется list comprehension.

Большое спасибо

@Altushka-97, если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый (галка напротив ответа).

Порядок циклов наоборот: tio.run.

@Qwertiy, точно, исправил

Улыбаюсь... Я понимаю, что это не ответ, но всё же, для справки...
n = sorted([1, 2, 3] * 2)
print(n) # результат: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]


Не факт, что данные всегда будут отсортированные приходить. Ну и лишняя сортировка. Так то короткий код, конечно.

Не понял о чём Вы. Пробуем ещё раз:
n = sorted([4, 1, 8, 2, 0, 3] * 2)
print(n) # результат: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8, 8]

Я о том, что не факт, что входящий список будет отсортированный и что на выходе тоже нужно получить отсортированный список. Может из списка [4, 1, 8, 2, 0, 3] нужно получить [4, 4, 1, 1, 8, 8, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3], не меняя порядок данных )  И сортировка это O(n log n), а просто проход по списку это O(n). Так то как вариант допустимо, но есть нюансы.

Автор так ставит задачу, что её можно понимать как угодно. Мне вообще сложно представить себе, кто такие задачи сочиняет. Я понять даже не могу, где такая ерунда может пригодиться. Тогда действительно вот так:
lst = [3, 5, 0, 4, 2]
doubled_lst = [item for item in lst for _ in range(2)]
print(doubled_lst)
Так мне посоветовал Тот-Кого-Тут-Нельзя-Цитировать и всё разжевал. Я понял его пояснения.
